# Why does NPM ask for peer dep's when it's clearly installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-amplify

Im working with AWS-Amplify and just updated it's CLI to the latest version, and now NPM complains that there are unmet dependencies, though graphql is clearly installed at the right version. What am missing here? Thanks for any clarification!

```sh
$ npm list -g --depth 0
/usr/local/lib
├── @aws-amplify/cli@4.12.0
├── @vue/cli@4.0.5
├── browser-sync@2.26.7
├── firebase-tools@7.10.0
├── graphql@14.5.8
├── nodemon@2.0.2
├── npm@6.13.6
└── parcel-bundler@1.12.4

npm ERR! peer dep missing: graphql@^14.5.8, required by @graphql-toolkit/file-loading@0.9.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: graphql@^14.2.0, required by relay-compiler@6.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your node version is not latest or when the dependencies require a certain version of other npm. Just check if all the npm packages and node is of latest version.